# How to find disjunction of two single linked lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

So if first list is 3, 6, 4, 5
And the second 6, 5, 7
The disjunction between two lists is 3,4,7

My idea was to compare all nodes from first list with all of them from second, so:

Comparing 3 to 5,6,7 and if neither is matched make a node in new list with value 3. But as the list goes on, when I compare the last node (5) with all other nodes in second that's the end of function, and the number 7 is missing from the disjucntion. Thats the problem.

Comment: By writing some code.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: List in ascending order?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be ascending.

Comment: It's quite simple. You need to find all numbers that don't appear in both lists.

Comment: Write some code and come back: Sort both lists, then compare. O(n*lg(n))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how you would do it in real life. If you had a set of 7 cards with numbers on them and one had {3, 4, 5, 6} and the other had {5, 6, 7} how do you go about finding the disjunction?

This might be a bit simple and not optimized but I would personally start out 'assuming' every element is in the disjunction.

Pseudocode:

```
Create a set of all the elements used at least once
making sure to have no duplicate elements in the set.
//In this particular problem: initial disjunctive array = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

For every element 'first' in the first set of cards:
    For every element 'second' in the second set of cards:
        If (first == second && first is still in the disjunctive array)
            Remove first from the disjunctive array
```

By removing all elements from the array that appear in both sets, you end up with the disjunction.

Answer (score 2):

Do the same thing with the second list. Take each element from second list, compare with each one of the first list. If not present, append to output list.

A more optimized method: Sort the two lists and compare the two.